# How to sum an amount by clusters and look up additional value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, left-join

I'm currently learning SQL and have the following problem, which should be easy to solve, but still no success: 
I have two tables: Transactions and Sites. In the Transactions table are all my order entries and in the Sites table are the information about my production sites. I now want to sum all the Sales clustered by the site and then show a table where you see the different sites, Sales per Site and the Adress of the site. For some reason that last step does not work. It only shows me "Null" values in the Adress column. When I choose Full outer join it does show me the adress but not in the corresponding line but in rows afterwards where the other two columns are then marked as Null. 
Any ideas?

```
 SELECT Transactions.Site, SUM(Transactions.Sales) AS [Sales_per_Site], 
 Sites.Adress
 From Transactions
 LEFT JOIN Sites ON Transactions.Site=Sites.Site
 Group by Transactions.Site, Sites.Adress
 ORDER BY Transactions.Site DESC

 Site   Sales     Adress
 5      16042772    NULL
 4      13163942    NULL
 3      14476761    NULL
 2      15912831    NULL
 1      13735548    NULL
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: are you sure Sites.Adress is not null ?

Comment: It can also be the join as you are left joining. Are you certain that Site is the same in both tables?

Comment: Hi! Yes there are values in the adress column for every five sites. Desired outcome would be the actual Adress and not "NULL"

Comment: Yes it's the same, sites from 1 to 5 in the transactions table and in the sites table, both in the column Site

Comment: I bet if you change from left to inner join you will get no records.

Comment: True, no records if I do a inner join

Comment: Therefore your join is wrong somehow. is Site an integer or text? You should put a select top 5 * from both tables in your question

Comment: Well that is why you get NULL. The join is not matching. Without sample data we can't do much more than point out why it isn't working. We can't actually help you fix it.

Comment: You're right, I just looked at it, in one table it is formatted as numeric value and in the other one it is formatted as varchar...

Answer (score 1):

> When I choose Full outer join it does show me the adress but not in
>   the corresponding line but in rows afterwards where the other two
>   columns are then marked as Null.

This almost certainly means that your two tables are not related to each other on the columns you are joining on:   `Transactions.Site=Sites.Site`

If you are really seeing sites 1-5 in both tables, then probably there is white space or something else in the columns causing the two sides to not actually be equal.

Comment: You're right, in one table "Site" is formatted as numeric value and in the other one it is formatted as varchar...

Comment: cast them both as integer CAST(t1.Site as int)=CAST(t2.Site as int)